# Dart: Accessing a class's variable when instantiating it

Tags: flutter, dart, class, variables

I just started learning Flutter (Dart) and I am really struggling despite my many years of experience in other languages.  What I try to do is very simple and yet seems to be impossible:

Given a sample constructor of TextField:

`TextField( labelText: "Something to do", onSubmitted: the_handler( a_textfield_variable) )`

Since most if not all Dart libraries define their variables final, the only way to initialize them is to use the constructor and it must be inline.  So how do I access a variable in the TextField while instantiate it?

From the sample above, the a_textfield_variable I mentioned is really the text that the user input.  However, since there doesn't seem to be anyway to access the value I have tried to use TextEditingController and it is another "short coming" of Dart.  I would need one for every TextField and I must put it outside of the TextField or its inheritance.

The bottom line is I am looking for a way to access a variable from a class at the construction time.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a way to make a sequence of operations on the same object while still returning the constructed object, use the [cascade notation](https://dart.dev/language/operators#cascade-notation).

```dart
var paint = Paint()
  ..color = Colors.black
  ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
  ..strokeWidth = 5.0;
```

---

The sample that you gave has nothing to do with accessing a member from the class.

The [`onSubmitted`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField/onSubmitted.html) parameter takes a `void Function(String)?` as the argument, so you can make a handler function that has a `String` parameter and pass it to `onSubmitted` like this:

```dart
void theHandler(String text) {
  // Do something with text
}
```

```dart
TextField(
  onSubmitted: theHandler,
)
```

Comment: I understand that.  However, the string you are talking about is the value that the user entered in the TextField.  Your suggestion doesn't fit the question, but thanks.  Like I said, I have tried to use the TextEditingController, which works fine but I have to create one TextEditingController for each TextField and it must be outside of the TextField class or its subclasses.  
I am looking for an easier or more appropriate way.

Comment: _"So how do I access a variable in the TextField while instantiate it"_ It's not clear what variable you're trying to access. Because the user input has nothing to do with the `TextField` class itself. `TextField` is just a widget that describes how the Flutter framework should render the UI.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, the user input must be stored somewhere in the TextField object.  If  I am, where would the user input be stored?

Comment: `TextField` is built on top of [`EditableText`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/EditableText-class.html), which is also a widget. `EditableText` interacts with `TextInput` service to handle user input. `EditableText` exposes user input the same way as `TextField`, which is through controller and `onChanged` (and other similar callback parameters). The `TextInput` service itself is not exposed as one of the widget's property. You can check the property list [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/EditableText-class.html#instance-properties)

Comment: Ok so based on what you said the controller holds the value.  So my question is how do I access the controller variable while instantiating the TextField.  like so:

TextField(..., onSubmitted: handler(thetextfieldobject.controller))
or 
TextField(..., onSubmitted: handler(thetextfieldobject.controller.text.toString()))

I understand that I can provide an external TextEdittingController and use it instead but my question isn't specific to the TextField.  There are many other classes have the same issue.

Just so you understand my question better.

Comment: I use TextField as the specific example for ease of understanding.  The question I asked is more general, for any class.

Comment: Ok so from my understanding, you're trying to access a member of the object that is not constructed yet, for use in one of the parameters that is used to construct the object itself. Is that true? If that's the case, then it's not possible at all.

Comment: If anything like that is needed, then the class would have an API that exposes its member to be accessed from, for example, a callback. There is no `this` access that directs to the object being constructed itself.

Comment: Also since you're looking for _easier or more appropriate way_, then I have to tell you, all of these "short comings" is the appropriate way.

Comment: @PhucLy Accessing a member variable *on the object you're instantiating* makes no sense.  The object doesn't exist yet.  That's doing step 2 before step 1.  Other programming languages would behave the same way.  Furthermore, even if you could do it, that variable has no value at that time!  What you want is the value (and in this case, the value of the `TextEditingController.text`) *later*, and that's what a callback is for. `TextField(controller: textController, onSubmitted: (text) { debugPrint(textController.text); })`.

Comment: @jamesdlin I know that but the way Dart is architected (implemented) is poor in my opinion.  The problem here is that the libraries declare everything final so all variables must be assigned in the constructor.  If I can (for the example above) assign the handler outside of the constructor then everything is fine.
The callback mechanism is fine, no complain there.  However, you have to create one callback per object.  So 10 textfields need 10 callback, 100 textfields need 100 callbacks.  Do you see why I say poor architecture?

Comment: @PhucLy You're complaining about the Flutter framework, not the Dart language.  Widgets generally have `final` fields to prevent mutation, and having immutable, stateless widgets is important to Flutter for performance.

Comment: @PhucLy That's solvable by extending the `TextField` class or creating a custom widget. You can put all the controller logic inside, and your custom class/widget can be used 100 times and will behave the same. If you ever need to access the controller of a specific instance, you would have exposed the controller through the parameter anyway. That applies to any other use cases.

Comment: @DhafinRayhan That was the second thing I tried after the external controller by subclassing the TextField, defined the external controller, and attempted to assign to the super.controller.  It wasn't compiling.  Again, the controller is final you can't assign it unless during the instantiation.

Comment: @PhucLy If anything then you implemented it wrong. This is a minimal working example of a text field that clears itself after the user submitted the input: [Example 1](https://gist.github.com/dhafinrayhan/a9a18ec4950e2c1fe734ae421697fce6). This is another example but the controller logic is completely inside the custom widget: [Example 2](https://gist.github.com/dhafinrayhan/8c87b3981378ae2f0a9177b94b6a21ef).

Comment: `class NumberField extends TextField
{
   TextEditingController c =  TextEditingController();
   NumberField({super.key, labelText, readOnly= false, floatingLabelBehavior =FloatingLabelBehavior.auto, onAccept}):
           super(obscureText: false,
               keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
               controller: c,
               readOnly: readOnly,
               decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: labelText,
                   floatingLabelBehavior: floatingLabelBehavior,
                   border: OutlineInputBorder())
       );
}`

Comment: Hmm. Code formatting isn't working as I thought it should.  
Anyway. Yes you are right, using widget like you did should work. But again it is more of a workaround instead of a solution.  That is not definition of extending.

Comment: @PhucLy "That's solvable by extending the TextField class **or** creating a custom widget." I've clearly said "or" as there are two ways you can achieve that. The example I gave is for the latter one.

Comment: @PhucLy Controller need a lifecycle, and that's specific to `StatefulWidget`. As you can see [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/text_field.dart#L203), even `TextField` does not extend `EditableText`, but it extends `StatefulWidget` and use `EditableText` in the `build` method. This is literally the solution, I don't see how you think this is not it. Also you haven't included any example from other frameworks where your ideal approach is implemented, which make it more confusing to see what you expect.

Comment: @DhafinRayhan The ideal or correct way to do this is to be able to extends the TextField directly as I coded above.  If you know older languages like C++ or Java you will know what I am talking about.  The thing you did is not extending.  It is called wrapping.   Here is what happens with the way you do when you extend a class ten times: 
You have 10 wrappers that extend widget
You have 9 widgets that are returned from the build methods.  
So there are lots of overheads.
Anyway, I was looking for a better way of accessing a class variables.  I guess it is impossible.
It is what it is.

Comment: @PhucLy Please **read** my comment above. I've clearly said **or** since the beginning, extending **OR** creating custom widget. I've never said they're the same thing. They are two different ways to achieve what you were trying to do. Also why don't you go ahead edit your question with the **example** for the readers of your post? That would make the post more clear.

Comment: @DhafinRayhan  I did try your solution and it worked for that specific variable, but it broke the other mechanism that I wanted to do.  What I want to do is more complex than just show the ui and read.  I have a couple of textfields whose values are inserted into an equation to solve for the missing variable.  So for 5 fields, user enters 4 fields and the equation will solve for the 5th.  Then it display the result in the 5th field.  So for each field I need to be able to get the value and set the values.  Anyway.  I have moved on to React Native.  Thanks for your attempts to help.